# How to display a snippet of a field in Expression Engine

Tags: content-management-system, expressionengine

I have a news section on my EE website where a user can add news articles.

The 3 last added articles will be displayed on the homepage with the News title, date and news body copy. Here's my code:

```
<ul>
 {exp:channel:entries channel="news" status="Featured|open" disable="catergories|member_data|pagination" limit="3"}
   <li>
     <h3><a href="{title_permalink=site/news"}">{title}</a></h3>
     <h4>{date}</h4>
     <p>{body}</p>
   </li>
 {/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```

Is there a way I can limit the {body} copy to only display a set a number of characters, so it displays a snippet/section of the text rather than all of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the EE documentation section on [plugins available for download](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/#available-for-download).

I think "Char Limit" would do what you want, alternatively look at "Word Limit".

Use like so:

```
{exp:char_limit total="100"}
{body}
{/exp:char_limit}
```

Comment: The 'Char Limit' worked perfectly, thanks for your help!